# Trabalhando com arrays, escolhendo apenas um dado

Tags: javascript, lógica

Posso ter uma composição de N elementos em um array que pode estar dispostos da seguinte maneira por exemplo:

array com A,B,C e D... 12 possibilidades.

```
arr1 = ["A|B","A|C","A|D","B|A","B|C","B|D","C|A","C|B","C|D","D|A","D|B","D|C"];
```

array com A,B e C... 9 possibilidades.

```
arr2 = ["A","B","C","A|B","A|C","B|A","B|C","C|A","C|B"];
```

Preciso criar um sorteio de modo que eu não tenha repetição de um dos elemento, exp:

```
arrDeSaida = ["B|A","D|C"]; //Válido
arrDeSaida = ["B|A","A|C"]; //inválido

arrDeSaida = ["B|C","A"]; //Válido
arrDeSaida = ["B|A","B"]; //inválido
```

A lógica simplesmente não está encaixando...

```
qtdElementos = ["A","B","C","D"];

for (var i = 0; i < qtdElementos.length; i++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < qtdElementos.length; x++) {
    if(x != i){
      arr1.push(qtdElementos[i]+'|'+qtdElementos[x]);
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= qtdElementos.length/2; i++) {
  if(arr1.length >= 2){
    posicao = arr1[i].split("|");
    for (var j = ; j < arr1.length; j++) {

    }
  }     
}
```

Travei dentro do segundo for, não sei o que poderia fazer..

Comment: Se no `arr1` já tem por exemplo `A|C` o "A" e "C" não podem mais ser sorteados?

Comment: sim, essa é a idéia

Answer (score 1):

Para sortear, já que não pretende repetir o valor, a cada sorteio remova o item sorteado ( igual um bingo por exemplo, onde se remove a bola sorteada). Pode-se fazer algo assim:

```
var sorteados = new Array();

function sortear(){
    // sorteia uma posição do array
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * paraSortear.length);
    // adiciona o item sorteado em um array de sorteados
    sorteados.push(paraSortear[index]);
    // remove o item sorteado do sorteio
    paraSortear.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Já para sortear todos os items faça um loop para continuar sorteando enquanto houver items a serem sorteados, algo assim:

```
while(paraSortear.length > 0){
    sortear();
}
```

É basicamente isso, no Array `sorteados`, você terá os items sorteados na ordem para manipular como desejar, no seu caso agrupando de 2 em 2.

Para agrupar como você citou de 2 em 2 você pode fazer assim:

```
function agrupar(array){
    var arrayAgrupado = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i+2) {
        arrayAgrupado.push(array[i] + (array[i + 1] ? "|" + array[i + 1] : ""));
    }
    return arrayAgrupado;
}
```

Com essa chamada:

```
var agrupados = agrupar(sorteados);
```

> [Exemplo completo online](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/7h1r5r3p/6/)

**Exemplo completo:**

```js
var paraSortear = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"];

var sorteados = new Array();

function sortear() {
  // sortea uma possição do array
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * paraSortear.length);
  // adiciona o item sorteado em um array de sorteados
  sorteados.push(paraSortear[index]);
  // remove o item sorteado do sorteio
  paraSortear.splice(index, 1);
}

function agrupar(array) {
  var arrayAgrupado = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
    arrayAgrupado.push(array[i] + (array[i + 1] ? "|" + array[i + 1] : ""));
  }
  return arrayAgrupado;
}

while (paraSortear.length > 0) {
  sortear();
}

var agrupados = agrupar(sorteados);

// limpa body
document.body.innerHTML = "";

function printJSON(value) {
  // para imprimir no DOM
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(value, null, 4)));
}

printJSON(agrupados);
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Então, no caso eu tenho uma lista de confrontos que já foram sorteados: `jogosFeitos= ["A|B","D|C"];` e uma lista de confrontos sugeridas pelo meu sistema, por exp: `jogosSugeridos= ["A|C","A|D","B|C","B|D", "C|A","C|B","D|A","D|B"];`
Era esse o ponto da minha pergunta, acho que de fato não devo ter me expressado bem rs

Comment: Não entendi @MarceloBonifazio?

Comment: A partir dos jogos sugeridos e dos jogos já feitos que eu sortearei o próximo jogo

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, não consegui entender usa duvida, nem seu cenário. Se puder editar sua pergunta com essas informações do comentário e talvez algum exemplo mais claro e explicativo do cenário e problema que precisa resolver, mais tarde posso tentar propor outra solução a seu problema.